# ReactJS doesn't work with Material Design Lite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

I'm developing a site with ReactJS and I'm using [MDL](https://www.getmdl.io/).

Well my problem is basically the css of the framework is working perfectly but for some reason the js of the framework doesn't work. As for example the [tabs](https://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/tabs)

[image]

but I saw when I refresh the page the js of the framework works.

[image]

I cannot see any error in the console. Any idea how to fix it and why is happening it? probably I'm adding the dependencies of the framework in a wrong way.

below is the code of my index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="Gonzalo Barba - personal website.">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

    <title>Gonzalo Barba</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,bold,italic,thin,light,bolditalic,black,medium&amp;lang=en">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.grey-pink.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="root" class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header"></div>

    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: MDL can't instantiate the JS for elements that aren't in the page at load (e.g. React components). Although why it works when you refresh, I'm not sure. See: https://www.getmdl.io/started/index.html#dynamic

Comment: ok.. then make sense. any idea how can I solve it? @JoeClay

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend using a library that wraps around the components to make things simpler - [React-MDL](https://tleunen.github.io/react-mdl/), for example. There's also other React material design component libaries which are custom built, rather than built around MDL, like [Material-UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/).